# Android gps retrieval

Tags: android, locationmanager, android-location

I have an app that track location using a location manager. I want to log a location when a user moved 100 feet, so I set up the listener to request updates for 100 feet and pass in a time of 30 seconds. I can see my gps icon blinking every 30 seconds so it is requesting a location. However, if I am it a building with a poor signal it will try CONSTANTLY to poll a gps location, so the signal never stops blinking, which drains the battery in a hurry. Is there a way to NOT poll for a gps location if it cannot get a signal right away? I tried passing in a large value for time (say 30 minutes) but then my gps only polls every 30 minutes, regardless of the distance I moved.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to understand how GPS works.  You don't poll GPS.  It requires you to continually track signals from a set of satellites.  You don't poll once and ignore it-  you continually track the signals.  In fact, it can take 10s of seconds to a few minutes to lock on to enough signals to triangulate your location.  So you can't just poll every 30 seconds or so.

If you want to use low battery, use network location and sacrifice accuracy.  If you want to know accurately when someone has moved 100 feet, you have to use GPS and take the hit.  You can't get both.

Comment: Thanks, my terminology wasn't the best. I realize that I don't manually "poll", that was just the observed behavior after setting up my listener of the gps attempting to get a location. My problem is that inside, as you said, it can take minutes to "lock on" and that is the battery issue, so I wanted it to "stop trying" if the gps couldn't find a location right away. Looks like I'll have to just take the battery hit, though, since I need to know when they move x amount of feet. Thanks

Comment: If you don't mind missing updates, you can always set a timer and turn off gps if it hasn't given you the update you need in time.  But then you won't get the location data.